# perl equivalent of pip freeze

Tags: python, perl

I would like to get the list of installed perl modules and versions under a given directory tree.

I would like to achieve the same task as in `pip freeze --user` for python modules.

We usually install software in a given directory eg `foo-1.0.0` will be installed to `/soft/foo/1.0.0` 
and required perl modules will be installed to `/soft/foo/1.0.0/lib/perl5`.

In order to be able to replicate the build and installation in the same condition we need to be able to get the list of perl modules installed AND their version.

Comment: Sounds like [carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) could help you with that.

Comment: I strongly recommend the carton approach going forward, it keeps track of exactly what you're asking for and makes reproducible deployments easy.

Comment: cartoon is not the answer to the question.
initial question is how to get the installed modules and generate the cpanfile 
cartoon will be a great tool in our install procedure, but we need to be abble to generate the list of modules from given tree

Answer (score 0):

use the following Perl program

```
#!perl
use ExtUtils::Installed;
my $inst = ExtUtils::Installed->new(@ARGV ? (inc_override => \@ARGV) : ());
my @modules = $inst->modules;
foreach (sort @modules) {
    print "$_ => ", $inst->version($_), "\n";
}
```

It takes a list of directories to search. If no paramaters are given it uses the contents of @INC

You could also use the autobundle feature of the CPAN module `perl -MCPAN -e autobundle` which will generate a bundle file of all installed modules

Comment: thanks, it sort out some of the problems we have.
some modules eg: Bio, XML::Parser are matched but noo version given.
I can live with that and dig myself to find the correct version used.